# How can i know what TextView was clickbale?

Tags: android, textview

i have one doubt. I have an iteration of TextViews, and what i want is when i click in one TextView , i want stop the iteration and open a web, who can i know what TextView as been click on? i have this code:

```
Iterator<TextView> it = text.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){

 test = it.next();




 test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
               //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
               mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                       view.loadUrl(url);
                       return true;
                   }
               });

           mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);


              }


              });



      // condition to stop the iteration when i click on TextView 
      }
```

And what i want is the condition to stop the iteration when i click on the TextView that i want see, i try using some methods that are in the TextView and don't work. Anyone can help me? I have the iteration of TextViews because i want to do this dynamic, and i don't know the TextView who as click, and i want to know what TextView was click to stop the iteration, because if i don't stop this, for example if i have 3 TextView they will open the same web.

Thanks and forgive my English

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you entirely but from what I understand you want to stop the Iteration when you click on a TextView.

So one way you can do it is. Declare a boolean property for this class to use to control the loop, in this case I called it **isStop** and initial value with **false**.

```
 while(it.hasNext() && !isStop){
...
    }
```

then

```
public void onClick(View v) {
isStop = true;
//mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
               mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                       view.loadUrl(url);
                       return true;
                   }
               });
```

So when you click on a TextView the flag will turn off the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i find the solution to what i want. I know the post that i put it's not clear. So i'm going to put the solution to what i want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to what i wanted:

On the Activity i create this.

```
OnClickListener s = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        text = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
};

Iterator<TextView> it = text.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    text = it.next();
    text.setOnClickListener(s);
}
```